# Tricky problem, looking at linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have encountered a question to which I have found an algebraic answer yet am still gasping for a geometric one (I want to know why the answer is so beautiful!) Here it is:

> Find $\det(δ_{ij} +a_i a_j)$

To find the reason I think the eigenvectors are crucial. But I don't see how I can find the answer for any n×n  matrix.

Please help!

Note:

A $2\times 2$ matrix would look like:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1+a_{1}^{2} & a_{1}a_{2}  \\
    a_{2}a_{1}& 1+a_{2}^{2}
  \end{bmatrix}

Comment: I just cannot understand what is the matrix $\;\delta_{ij}+a_ia_k\;$ ...What are those $\;a_ia_k\;$ ?

Comment: So is your matrix indexed by $i,j$ or $i,k$?

Comment: All of this does not make much sense. Why should you ignore higher order terms? This can be done only for small eigenvalues, since for example $$\det (\delta_{ij}+\delta_{ij})=2^n \neq 1+n = 1+ \operatorname{Tr}(\delta_{ij})$$

Comment: Crostul, you're correct. The second solution is no good. I will edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This matrix has one eigenvector $a$ with eigenvalue $1+|a|^2$, and the orthogonal complement of $a$ is an eigenspace with eigenvalue $1$. Thus the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, $1+|a|^2$.

Comment: @Novice: I don't think you ever defined $A$, but I gather you mean $A_{ij}=a_ia_j$. Then yes, $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\sum_ia_i^2=|a|^2$.

Comment: Joriki, could you please explain why the one of the eigenvalues is 1+|a|^2 and the eigenspace of the orthogonal complement has value 1? 

I still don't understand :(

Comment: @Novice: The matrix with entries $A_{ij}=a_ia_j$ can be written as $A=aa^\top$. Then $Aa=(aa^\top)a=a(a^\top a)=|a|^2a$, so $a$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $|a|^2$. For any vector $b$ orthogonal to $a$, we have $Ab=(aa^\top)b=a(a^\top b)=0\cdot a$, so the orthogonal complement of $a$ is an eigenspace with eigenvalue $0$. Now we just have to add the $1$ from the identity.

Comment: It all clicks together. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me understand this problem. Thank you.